# Sort by date in "dbReadtable" (in R)

Tags: r, database, datatable

I have a dbReadtable which I wanna sort by date. My table looks as follow:

```
Id Date       Number
1  2020-11-01 1
2  2020-11-03 3
3  2020-11-02 4
4  2020-11-01 2
5  2020-11-02 4
6  2020-11-03 3
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
Date       Number
2020-11-01 3
2020-11-02 8
2020-11-03 6
```

I use the following code for the table:

```
data <- dbReadTable(con, "observations")
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Try:  library(dplyr) df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Number = sum(Number))  where df is your dataframe

Comment: You mean like this: data %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Number = sum(Number))

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you load the dplyr library ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following SQL statement. We use the input in the Note at the end and `sqldf` to make it reproducible but you can use the same SQL statement with whatever is appropriate for your database.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Date, sum(Number) as Number from data group by Date order by Date")
```

giving:

```
        Date Number
1 2020-11-01      3
2 2020-11-02      8
3 2020-11-03      6
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Id Date       Number
1  2020-11-01 1
2  2020-11-03 3
3  2020-11-02 4
4  2020-11-01 2
5  2020-11-02 4
6  2020-11-03 3"
data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the '''Lubridate::wday'''', to get which week has the highest frequency (assuming the data file would be longer)?

Comment: Seems like a completely different question.